# How to detach database and copy db file in local device programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to detach the database from SQL Server 2005 from my C# code. I use the DROP query to detach. But it statements delete the file from my local system. I want to detach the database and copy that database in runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Server SMO API let's you do anything Sql Server management studio can do (from c# code).
Check out this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162175.aspx

Comment: I have tested Backing Up and Restoring Database From your link above. Backing up is successful, but restoring can't do. It shows me error "Restoring failed to my server". What do i need to do?

Comment: Hi All, I've solve this problem. I use SMO Library and I use this code. Server myserver = new Server(). myserver.DetachDatabase("Database",true).

Answer (score 3):

First try to connect to the `SQL Server` without providing any database name,or path just like below:

```
ConnectionString = @"Data Source= YourDataSource ;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
```

Note:
YourDataSource can either be `.` or `.\SQLEXPRESS`  or `.\MSSQLSERVER` or `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` or `(localdb)\v11.0` or etc.

Then by using the following query, detach your database.

```
"ALTER DATABASE [your DB] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE \n\r exec sp_detach_db @dbname = [your DB]";
```

## Ok.

My Sample code:

```
sql_connect1.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
sql_command.CommandText = "ALTER DATABASE [IRAN] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE \n\r exec sp_detach_db @dbname = [IRAN]";
                  sql_command.Connection = sql_connect1;
                  sql_connect1.Open();
                  sql_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  sql_connect1.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can detach a database on SqlServer by the following code:
There is a stored procedure in SqlServedr 'sp_detach_db' for detach a database, has one argument DataBaseName. Here in the code 'MyDatabase' is the database name you should change it with your database name

```
// C# Code

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=(local); Data Source=;Integrated Security=SSPI");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", conn);

cmd.CommandText = "sys.sp_detach_db MyDatabase";

conn.Open();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.Dispose();
conn.Dispose();
```

Comment: This does not work always. I get an exception "Cannot detach the database 'TestDatabase' because it is currently in use."

Comment: So, before detach it, you have to break all connections, this happens when we detach database through Sql Management Studio, a check named "Close existing connections" is there. You can find code to click on button named "Sql"(on top of the window)

Answer (score 0):

You can use stored procedures for your problem. following link can be useful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259611.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Myo Thu's comments lead me in the right direction, so here's a summary of steps on how to detach the database.

Step 1: Reference the following DLL's in your project [[Reference]](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162129.aspx):

> Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll

Step 2: using:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
```

Step 3: Code

```
var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(@"MyMachine\SQL2012"));
// Ensure database is not in use
server.KillAllProcesses("TestDatabase");
server.DetachDatabase("TestDatabase", true);
```

EDIT: Now documented in my blog [here](http://sudhanshutheone.net/2014/05/28/execute-sql-batch-queries-using-c-and-smo-magic/)